# The JAVA program runs faster in Netbeans then in CMD

Tags: java, netbeans

My `java` (big project) runs faster in Netbeans then cmd.

Elapsed time in netbeans is **1s**.
Elapsed time in cmd is **10s**.

(It is not a coincidence , I tried many times)
I am using same JDK 1.7.

Do you have any idea why?

Comment: The console on CMD is really slow.  Can you redirect the output to a file and see how long it takes.

Comment: Did you pass any JVM options on the console? Maybe Netbeans starts your program with a bigger heap or something like that.

Comment: Don't know about netbeans. If it doesn't spawn a new process it will be way faster than CMD since the JVM is already up and running. Java is a slow starter.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: The program write to console(using System.out.println()) write only 4lines. I do not think it would be a reason for slowdown. @Matze: no, only `java -jar myProgram.jar`

Comment: @PanTau redirecting them to a file and find out (unlikely but easy to try) `java -jar myProgram.jar > output.log`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NetBeans always prints the final command on how it executes the project depending on build system (Ant, Maven, Gradle) in the console.

You should be able to copy it and paste it into CMD and the result should be very similar. Look at the Output window, e.g. for Maven:

```
cd /Users/crazyjavahacking/NetBeansProjects/root/mavenproject1; JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home "/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.0.1.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/java/maven/bin/mvn" "-Dexec.args=-classpath %classpath org.crazyjavahacking.mavenproject1.JavaApplication11" -Dexec.executable=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Dexec.classpathScope=runtime org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec
```

**The performance degradation has to be caused by something, very unlikely caused by CMD itself.**

Comment: Thank you for your reply, where can I find this: `You should be able to copy it and paste it into CMD` ?